# Position buttons at the middle heigth of the two sides of an img

Tags: html, css, image, button

I have this simple HTML code, with a div that contains an img and 2 buttons:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="....">
    <button id="lefBTN"> .... </button>
    <button id="rightBTN"> .... </button>
</div>
```

May anyone tell me how I can position, using CSS, the two buttons respectively to the left and to the right of the image, at the middle heigth of the two sides?

The image can be oriented both vertically and horizontally, but the two buttons must always be positioned at half height of its two sides, like in this figure:

[image]

Comment: You'll have to wrap the buttons under one `div` and use `display: flex;` and `justify-content` to add some space in between the buttons. And you'll need to `absolutely position` the button div above the image (`relatively positioned`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution will be using **inline rendering** + **absolute positioning**
inside...

**Inline rendering** is "non greedy" and the container always tries to use the most less space.

**Absolute positioning** will be used for placing your buttons anywhere you like, while the most closest parent having a relative position will be the reference.

Additionally **transformations** will be helpful, since they always uses the own element's dimensions for calculations, so you safely can use `-50%` for centering. I really recommend that, because it won't matter how large the buttons are.

I recommend you to experiement a little bit with the coords and properties for a better understanding.

```css
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
}

img { 
  background: grey;
  width: 400px;
  height: 150px;
}

#lefBTN,
#rightBTN { 
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  padding: 10px;
  background: darkblue; 
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid darkblue;
}

#lefBTN {
  left: -10px;
}

#rightBTN {
  right: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <img src="..."/>
    <button id="lefBTN">lB</button>
    <button id="rightBTN">rB</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! That's what I needed!